# Saucer with 3 beings of light who exit over the ocean

Tags: story-identification, movie

A man sees a saucer just offshore over the ocean. It tips sideways vertically and 3 beings of light float out of the saucer. I think saw this movie in either the 70s or80s.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  There really isn't a lot here to go on.  Can you [edit] in anything else you can think of, like where you saw it (country, TV channel or VHS, etc.)?  How do you know it's an ocean, not a lake?

Comment: Could be [Cocoon 1/2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zohgyAAKF6M), please post more information: how these beings of light looked like, what was their goal, etc.

Comment: It definitely was not the cocoon series of movies.  This was an obscure movie I've seen only once and the fact that I only remember this very strange saucer (very dark or black in color)

Comment: @TedKeesey how those beings of light looked like?

Comment: The 3 beings of light did not have human form.  They were vertical lights.  I'll research this further and let everyone know what I find.  I realize I haven't given you much to go on so to be fair I'll do more research since I know the exact scene.  Thank you!

Comment: Might be Intruders (1992) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAYYQJnRpH4 you can see the ship here

Answer (score 2):

Ok, just to give it a try: it could be [Cocoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoon_(film)) and [Cocoon: The Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocoon:_The_Return)

"Cocoon" movie plot

> About 10,000 years ago, peaceful aliens from the planet Antarea set up
> an outpost on Earth on Atlantis. When Atlantis sank, twenty aliens
> were left behind, kept alive in large rock-like cocoons at the bottom
> of the ocean. Now, a group of Antareans have returned to collect them.
> Disguising themselves as humans, they rent a house with a swimming
> pool and charge the water with "life force" to give the cocooned
> Antareans energy to survive the trip home. They charter a boat from a
> local captain named Jack, who helps them retrieve the cocoons. Jack
> spies on Kitty, a beautiful woman from the team who chartered his
> boat, while she undresses in her cabin, and discovers that she is an
> alien. After the aliens reveal themselves to him and explain what's
> going on, he decides to help them.

"Cocoon: The return" movie plot

> Five years after they left Earth following a failed rescue mission,
> the Antareans return to rescue the cocoons that were left behind.
> Before they can be retrieved, one of the cocoons is discovered by a
> science research team and taken to a secure laboratory for testing.
> The aliens and their human allies must find a way to retrieve the
> cocoon in time for their rendezvous with the rescue ship, while the
> humans travelling with them must decide whether to return to Antarea
> or stay on Earth and become mortal again.

Saucer over the ocean:
[image]

[image]

Beings of the light:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Yaroslav.  The short clip of the movie I saw was definitely not Cocoon 1 or 2.  I'll continue to look in the 60s, 70s, 80s and 90s sci fi and let everyone know what I find.   I know my description is very short.  Maybe I caught the end of this film. I'm not sure.  Hopefully more later.  Thank you!